# Indy Node installation issue in ubuntu

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-indy

I am trying to install Hyperledger Indy Node on ubuntu but facing the issue

Here is the log :

```
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! build error 
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! cwd /home/indy/node_modules/indy-sdk
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! node -v v13.1.0
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
indy-nodejs  | gyp ERR! not ok 
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! errno 1
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! indy-sdk@1.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! Exit status 1
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! 
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! Failed at the indy-sdk@1.11.0 install script.
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
indy-nodejs  | 
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
indy-nodejs  | npm ERR!     /home/indy/.npm/_logs/2019-11-16T04_46_31_837Z-debug.log
indy-nodejs exited with code 1
```

Comment: whenever i am trying to installing node js in hyperledger-indy that time came like this errrorr

Comment: any one know solution about this issue please post

Comment: which node version do you use? did you try v10?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809), you can try:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. delete `~/.node-gyp`, `~/.npmrc` folder and `node_modules` in your project then restart your computer
3. use `node` with version `11.0.0`
4. make sure you have [libindy.dylib](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/samples/nodejs)

Comment: but actually ~/.node-gyp file are not in my file and also essentialy not bulding here actuly i am getting like this error when i am "sudo apt-get install build-essential " write this command           
 libpython-all-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libpython-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-dev (>= 2.7.12-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-dev (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).